# How to use PHP variables on HTML page?

Tags: php, html

I am designing one HTML form with index.html page. Default values are on PHP page, like name, for form. Now my query is how can I take these values on to the HTML page?

For example :

default.php

```
$name="poorna";
...
...
```

in index.html

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" >
</form>
```

How can this be possible ?

Comment: you can't do it untill the index.html is an php page `index.php`

Comment: You need to tell apache to resolve html as php, also you will need to include default.php in it, because $name is not in the file scope, nor in the session, or any other global

Answer (score 3):

quick and dirty:

change index.html to index.php

```
<?php include 'default.php'; ?>

<form>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" >
</form>
```

hope it helps

for a shorter version of echo you can use `<?= $name ?>;`.

Notice:

the short tags only work if you set the correct setting in the php.ini

```
$ grep 'short_open' php.ini-production
; short_open_tag
short_open_tag = On //Default Off
```

If i am not wrong since PHP 5.4 this option is set to On by default

Comment: Sometimes it won't work. <? ?> Interpreter was not accepting short tags

Comment: yes you are right, edited my answer :) didnt think about the php version

Answer (score 1):

Without .php extension server dont accept   php tag. Save the file as php is better...

Comment: I think for HTML doesn't need server change the file to index.php extension itself need server.